Drying time for 10”x4’ Ebony log
How long should I allow my 4’ long log of 10” diameter ebony air dry before processing into live edge planks? I live on the equator.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This isn't generally how you dry wood, as even the most scant research will bring up. Additionally which species is this? Ceylon ebony, gaboon or macassar? This is a factor in expected drying performance, but regardless it will be very important to seal the end grain well (as covered in numerous sources). Do not overlook this step and don't delay, it should be done ASAP, immediately if possible.

Does this answer your question? How best to dry Ebony?

Well, often wood rule of thumb is 1 year per inch.  so 10 years?
More realistically, logs are generally cut into lumber and then left to dry, and I would wax the ends of the log (before or after cutting) because it looks like Ebony can get some pretty severe checking as it dries.
So that would be my recommendation, cut the log into 'reasonable' lumber sizes (Remember that you'll need them to be a little bigger than what you want in final dimensions), Wax the end grain and then stack the milled wood with 'stickers' to allow it to air dry.  and depending on the sizes you cut it could be a year or 2 after that.
I don't know an actual drying time for Ebony and depending on local weather patterns (jungle vs desert etc) can make a huge difference in drying time.

I would add that the wood should be acclimated to the temperature and humidity conditions it will live in for a period before it is finished.

I would normally upvote this, but in the same spirit that we're not supposed to Answer bad Questions (this is a prime example of one of the two reasons to downvote)..... plus it's a possible dupe.
